# kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException when acces through view model

Tags: android, kotlin

I've view model with MutableLiveData that look like this:

```
private val _num = MutableLiveData<Float>()

val num: LiveData<Float>
    get() = _num 

val sum: Int= sumMap.map { it.value }.sumBy { it.num}

_num.value = sum.toFloat()
```

I'm able to get the value correctly, but when I tried to access through the viewmodel objec, I get

> kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Why I'm getting this error? my code in my fragment look like this:

```
   val dVal: Float = viewModel.num.value!!
            Log.i("MainScreenFragment", "numVal $dVal")
```

Also, If I remove the `!! assertion`, I get `required Float but found Float?`, Why is this? I didn't declare my variable at any point as nullable

**EDIT:**

This is the entire function, this function called inside `init` block

```
private fun getPlacesCountries() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        var getPlacesDeffers = PlaceApi.retrofitService.getPropeties()
        try {
            var result = getPlacesDeffers.await()
            if (result.isNotEmpty()) {
                val sumMap: Map<String, Data> = result.mapValues { (country,data) -> data.last() }

                val sum: Int= sumMap.map { it.value }.sumBy { it.num }

                _num.value = sum.toFloat()
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _response.value = "Failure: ${e.message}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `val dVal: Float = viewModel.num.value!!` is this line outside a function and is defined as a class member variable?

Comment: `value` on `LiveData` is a `T?`, not a `T`, because the `LiveData` does not always have a value to return, so it returns `null` by default. In terms of your error, in the future, please post the entire stack trace, not just one line. It is also unclear how to interpret your first code snippet, as the last line (`_num.value = sum.toFloat()`) is just floating around. You might consider posting the entire class, not just a few lines.

Comment: @sonnet - this line is inside a function in my fragment, that accept the viewModel object and this function responsible of creating a chart.

Comment: @commomsWare - My entire class is long and i tought if I posted just the relevant lines it become more clear, the '_num.value = sum.toFloat()' is just because the sum return int, and i need float. I also do able to get the correct value inside the view model.   I'll edit my post and add the entire flow hope it'll become more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity/fragment you need to observe LiveData:

```
viewModel.num.observe(this, Observer {
   it?.let { chart.setData(it) } // set values if it is not null
})
```